# How to import types from npm package using vite?

Tags: typescript, npm, build, vite

I'm writing a package with a couple of `ts` functions, which will be used by several repos (mobile and web app). As a build tool, our team is always using `vite`, therefore it is also used in the repo.

I have the following `vite.config.ts` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: { // required, because it is actually the library, whitout any 'index.html'
      name: 'project-name',
      entry: './src/index.ts',
      fileName: 'index',
      formats: ['cjs', 'umd'] // not sure about this line, but in helped to generare 'index.js' and 'index.umd.js' files in the build
    },
    outDir: 'dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true // without this line, the `index.d.ts` file is not generating at all
    })
  ]
})
```

And the following `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

`package.json` contains the following paths:

```json
{
  ...,
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "module": "./dist/index.umd.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.umd.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  ...
}
```

The problem is, when the package is installed in other repos, the types are not loaded, so all classes have `any` type, all functions are of `any` type and so on. Even types are not imported validly and are marked by VS Code as `any`. Type information is important for me, and I want it to be exported validly

What have I tried:

1. Usage of `vite-tsconfig-paths` plugin instead of `vite-plugin-dts`. It didn't even generate any `*.d.ts` file in the `/dist` folder
2. Different `tsconfig` options. It feels like the plugin doesn't even see the `tsconfig.json` file (named validly, is also in a root directory)

Additional comments:

- types are exported using syntax `export type ...`
- in `src/index.ts` there is an import of everything, including types
- the `index.d.ts` file, which is generated now, contains single line:

```
export * from './index'
```

Which means, it exports just the content of `index.js`, generated by the build

Comment: Did you ever discover a solution to this? In the same boat

Comment: @JabbaWook, yes. The solution is - you just need `tsc` and nothing more to build pure ts repo. In my case `vite` was redundant

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I'll give tsc a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases you don't need `vite` or `webpack` to build a package. In the described case, pure `tsc` was enough